# Image over a Image

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i want to put a Big image over a small Image , condition is the image which is on top has some specific rectangular area where the second image will be displayed. I want the the small Image to be displayed inside the big image not over the big image. i don't no will it possible or not , if it is possible can any one provide me guidance or provide me a sample code or link

thanks alot

Comment: How do you display the small image inside the big image but not over it.  If the small image is not over the big image the small image will not be see.

Comment: i want to make a small part of big image transparent and then displaying the small image behind that image

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution. Why don't you put the small image *on top* of the big image? Will that work? That way the illusion is the same that the small image is inside. Otherwise you have to play around with alpha transparency.

PS. Rupesh, you should also go back to the 13 questions that you asked prior to this one and accepted at least some answers. Otherwise chances are you will not get many answers later on to any of your new questions, because you are not *rewarding* the people that take time to answer your questions, with positive karma.

Comment: i will definitely going to reward the people thanks for reminding i dint no that i need to reward as i am new to this forum, from next time onwards i will do so.

i am able to place small image over the big image, but i don't want to do like that, actually i want to place behind the big image. as i am new to blackberry application development i don't no about alpha transparency. the big image where the small image will get fit that region will be transparent but i don't no how to make that specific region transparent . i hope this question is clear thanks for your help and suggestion.